# Indesign server - generate indesign file based on data & provided template

Tags: web, server, adobe-indesign

i want to build a webform to store the values that i want to place in various indesign templates, to generate an indesign file. How do i do it?

How would i generate the indesign file if i have the template and the database of values that need to be placed on correct positions on the template.

Answer (score 0):

Download InDesign Server SDK. It has PHP and JAVA Samples that will help you setting the environment. IDS is also available as a demo for 90days if I recall well.
Basically you write a jsx script which will do the placements and tell IDS to execute that script with specific arguments.